# Can Chord of Shards be cast any time, or only during a performance?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, bard

Do you already have to be in a bardic performance to cast [Chord of Shards](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/chord-of-shards), effectively taking two rounds to cast, or could you freely cast it as a standard action whenever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A [bard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard) can cast [*chord of shards*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/chord-of-shards) when he wants, but the spell only has an effect during the bard's own [bardic performance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard#TOC-Bardic-Performance)

The 1st-level [bard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard) spell [*chord of shards*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/chord-of-shards) can be cast effectively only during a round in which one of the bard's own [bardic performances](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard#TOC-Bardic-Performance) is ***either*** started (as a standard action at levels 1-6 and optionally as a move action at levels 7-12 and optionally as a swift action at levels 13 or higher) ***or*** maintained (as a free action). (To be clear, *Pathfinder* creative director James Jacobs clarifies that [casting a spell doesn't interfere with a bardic performance](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ljwf?Bardic-Performance-and-Spell-Casting#9).)

This, indeed, makes the spell *chord of shards* a resource hog for a low-level bard that might only have a handful of level 1 spells per day (as few as 2 at level 1), spells known (also 2 at level 1), and rounds per day of bardic performance (usually only 5 to 8); this is on top of concerns about the spell taking, effectively, 2 standard actions for the low-level bard to eventually cast. I'd urge *any* bard instead toward the spells [*charm person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-person), [*grease*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/grease), or [*silent image*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/silent-image), or, if damage *must* the bard's goal, [*ear-piercing scream*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/ear-piercing-scream).

Keep in mind, as ShadowKras's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/84491/8610) mentions, the spell *chord of shards*, in fact, *can* be cast when the bard's *not* using a bardic performance, but nothing happens, and the bard will have expended one his precious spells per day to no effect. Further, if Abe the bard is merely reaping the benefits of Bob the bard's bardic performance, Abe the bard will find his *chord of shards* spell cast to no effect, it being *during* Bob's—not Abe's—bardic performance.

Answer (score 2):

> During your bardic performance,

The spell text is pretty clear, however, you can cast the spell without being in a bardic performance, but since the spell duration is **instantaneous**, the spell will simply fail because it cannot do anything if you are not in a bardic performance.

Note that the spell does not require you to be in a bardic performance to be cast; that would most likely be part of the component section, or the spell text would declare that it can only be cast during a bardic performance. But you do need to be in a bardic performance for its effect to do anything.

Keep in mind as well that bardic performance is a move action by 7th level, and swift action by 13th level.

Comment: bardic performances can be kept going as a free action too, so there's that.